# Display elements from a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm facing a weird problem; I'm trying to display all the tasks associated to a staff member, and there is an error that I don't understand:

- I can only access to the id of the task

My code =

Staff index :

```
<% @staffs.each do |staff| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to staff.name, staff %>
    </td>
    <%staff.tasks.each do |task| %>
      <td>
        <%= task.id %> / 
      </td>
    <%end%>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Staff controller :

```
class StaffsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! 
  skip_before_action :configure_sign_up_params
  before_action :set_staff, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /staffs
  # GET /staffs.json
  def index
    @staffs = current_user.staffs
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_staff
      @staff = Staff.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def staff_params
      params.require(:staff).permit(:name, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Staff model :

```
    class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  has_many :ranches_staff
  has_many :ranches, through: :ranches_staff
  has_many :staffs_task
  has_many :tasks, through: :staffs_task
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: Can you add the error you get? Maybe add the Staff model as well.

Comment: Hi @Ursus, thanks for your answer, My error is:

undefined method `name' for #<Task:0x007f83471b2818>
I added the model staff in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to access the attributes of the task object. The task object is a nested attribute of the staff object. To access this you need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to access `task` from `staff` as follows:

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staff
end
```

**Edit:**
Now that you have made it clear that the `staff` class has a `through` relationship with `staffs_task` I think that the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` relationship should be with `:staffs_task` as follows:

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :staffs_task
  has_many :tasks, through: :staffs_task
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :staffs_task, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: Hi @Dawcars, thanks for your answer, the thing is that Task is a nested form of a Ranch model. But the weird stuff is that I can call the id of the task, but not the others variables.
So should I have to define a set_ranch or set_task into my staff controller ?